# Cumulative sum in PowerPivot

Tags: excel, pivot, powerpivot, dax

Tried for a while now, but I couldn't solve the following issue:

I have a data table in Excel, which looks like the following:

[Data Source Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eykX9.jpg)

What I'd like to have is this:

[Output from PowerPivot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ozae7.jpg)

I encountered the following issue:

- When I filter for the current YearMonth (in my example 201602), the row "Apple" disappears, as there is no sales of apples in 201602. However, there is a history of sales for apples, which are cumulated (Column: Sales of Country to Date). Also, there is a forecast, which is the total of past sales and future sales of apples (Colomn: Sales of Country Forecast).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have a date table in your PowerPivot model?

If yes, this will make your life much easier since you can use the time intelligence functions.

Comment: Not yet, but if it helps, I'd certainly create one...

Comment: Once you create your date table, you might find the accepted answer in this post useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18275270/dax-running-total-or-count-across-2-groups